# How to use map_if based on the name of each element in the list

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

suppose I have a list of dataframes as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a1 = 1:5, a2 = 1:5, a3 = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(a1 = 1:3, a2 = 2:4, a3 = 3:5)
df3 <- data.frame(a1 = 10:20, a2 = 5:15)

l <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)
```

What should I do to perform operations (like `mutate`) on each element on the list conditioning on the elements name?

For instance - how would I proceed If I wanted to add some new column only if was dealing with `df1` or `df3` and wanted to delete some column if I was dealing with `df2`?

Could `map_if` deal with that?

PS: Keep in mind that the list would probably have more than 3 datasets so that possibly multiple conditions would be needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this sort of operations with `imap` instead. Since you would like to do a certain operations based on names of the your list or names of the elements of the list you should use `imap`.

`.f` argument in `imap` takes 2 arguments:

- `.x` which is the first argument and represents the value
- `.y` which is the second argument and represents the names of you arguments and in case they don't have names, it represents their positions

So for example in this case `.x`s are your 3 data sets and `.y`s are their names `df1:df3` or their positions `1:3`.

```
library(purrr)

l %>%
  imap(~ if(.y %in% c("df1", "df3")) {
    .x %>% 
      mutate(a3 = a1 + a2)
  } else {
    .x <- .x[-3]
    .x
  })

$df1
  a1 a2 a3
1  1  1  2
2  2  2  4
3  3  3  6
4  4  4  8
5  5  5 10

$df2
  a1 a2
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  3  4

$df3
   a1 a2 a3
1  10  5 15
2  11  6 17
3  12  7 19
4  13  8 21
5  14  9 23
6  15 10 25
7  16 11 27
8  17 12 29
9  18 13 31
10 19 14 33
11 20 15 35
```

But if you would like to apply a certain function on each of your elements that meets a certain condition then you can use `map_if`. For example we would like to add `a4` column if the number of rows in each are greater than a certain number. Bear in mind that `.p` argument should return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

```
# This use case works 
l %>%
  map_if(~ nrow(.x) > 3, ~ .x %>%
           mutate(a4 = a1 + a2))

# But this doesn't becase names(.x) are actually column names of each element and the result is not what you are after
l %>%
  map_if(~ names(.x) %in% c("df1", "df3"), ~ .x %>%
           mutate(a4 = a1 + a2))
```

An equivalent to `imap` is `map2` where the second argument is the names of each element (and not the column names of each element):

```
l %>%
  map2(names(l), ~ if(.y %in% c("df1", "df3")) {
    .x %>% 
      mutate(a3 = a1 + a2)
  } else {
    .x <- .x[-3]
    .x
  })
```